# Xamarin Capabilites not detected when using Azure Dev Ops Docker Agent

Tags: docker, visual-studio, xamarin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use Azure Dev Ops Self hosted Docker Agent, the agent is connecting fine and the Docker image is building fine, but for some reason these Capabilities are not detected

There is no Troubleshooting Documentation on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

Is there any other way to install Visual Studio for Docker so that the Azure DevOps agent detects all the workloads ?

```
[error]No agent found in pool Dockerized which satisfies the following demand: Xamarin.Android. All demands: MSBuild, Xamarin.Android, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1
```

Dockerfile

```
# escape=`


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019


SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `

    curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe `
    `
    && (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache modify `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.XamarinBuildTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.UniversalBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools ` 
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1 ` 
        --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.5.0 ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.29.16.11.x86.x64 ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.29.16.11.x86.x64.Spectre ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.30.17.0.x86.x64 ` 
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools `
        --add Component.Android.SDK25 `
        --add Component.Android.SDK23 `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe

CMD [ "C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass" ]


WORKDIR /azp

COPY start.ps1 .

CMD powershell .\start.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue, the problem was the windows servercore version switching to **20H2** fixed the issue

Updated Dockerfile

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2

# Download channel for fixed install.
ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

# Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_BuildTools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.XamarinBuildTools`
    --add Component.Xamarin.Profiler`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install node.js & set Environment PATH.
RUN msiexec.exe /i https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-x64.msi /qn

# Start agent
WORKDIR /azp
COPY start.ps1 .
CMD powershell .\start.ps1
```